# How to DRY up an if else Ruby function?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can this bit of Ruby code be refactored to make it less ugly:

```
def default_item_price(user)
  if project.present?
    if project.hourly_rate?
      project.hourly_rate
    elsif project.person.hourly_rate?
      project.person.hourly_rate
    elsif project.person.organisation && project.person.organisation.hourly_rate?
      project.person.organisation.hourly_rate
    else
      user.preference.hourly_rate     
    end
  else
    user.preference.hourly_rate
  end
end
```

I haven't done a lot of Ruby programming and I wonder if the last 6 lines can be DRYed up somehow. Thanks for any help!

These are my Models:

```
class User
  has_many :people
end

class Person
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :projects

  def real_hourly_rate
    hourly_rate || organisation.real_hourly_rate
  end    
end

class Project
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :invoices

  def real_hourly_rate
    hourly_rate || person.real_hourly_rate
  end
end

class Invoice
  belongs_to :project

  def default_item_price(user)
    project.real_hourly_rate || user.preference.hourly_rate    
  end
end
```

Comment: For refactoring questions you should use http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to rethink your design a bit. You've got hourly rates on at least four different classes, which is a bit of a mess. I understand you're trying to assign default values based on associations that can be overridden by more localized ones, but you're doing all of the overriding in whatever class this is (almost certainly not the class that should be responsible for it).

Take `person`: if a person has a specific hourly rate, get that, otherwise, get the person's organization's hourly rate. This logic belongs in the `Person` class, with a method in the public interface that allows you to query this in one step, say `person.real_hourly_rate`. You can do the same sort of thing with `project`.

Eventually, if your classes have nice, well-defined apis, you should be able to define this method as something like:

```
def default_item_price(user)
  project_hourly_rate || user.preference_hourly_rate
end
```

Here, the intention is clear, the grunt work is distributed among the classes it needs to be, and the method is readable and understandable by anyone who picks up your code.

There's a handy rails method called `delegate` that might help you out with some of this:

```
class Project
  delegate :hourly_rate, to: :person, prefix: true, allow_nil: true

  def real_hourly_rate
    hourly_rate || person_hourly_rate
  end
```

This `real_hourly_rate` method (perhaps that's not the best name for it) will give you the hourly rate if it exists, and if not, it will ask the associated person for its hourly rate.

Comment: Thanks Zach! What you say makes total sense to me and I have been trying to implement it. However, for some reason I can't get it to work. I updated my schema above, so you can see where my `default_item_price` method should go. I still don't understand why I need a `real_hourly_rate` method when I already have a `delegate` statement in my model.

Comment: Scrap that, I actually got it working. I posted my code above. I am just confused because I am not using the `delegate` method you suggested.

Comment: Great, it looks much better.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Zach. Here is a dryer rewrite anyway!

```
def hourly_rate_from anything
  anything.hourly_rate? ? anything.hourly_rate : nil
end

def default_item_price user
  if project.present?
    rate = hourly_rate_from project
    rate ||= hourly_rate_from project.person
    if project.person.organisation
      rate ||= hourly_rate_from( project.person.organisation ) 
    end
    return rate if rate
  end
  hourly_rate_from user.preference
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Java et al, in Ruby `&&` and `||` return one or the other of their arguments. This can be used to make code which has a series of null checks very concise:

```
def default_item_price(user)
  if project.present?
    project.hourly_rate ||
    project.person.hourly_rate ||
    (project.person.organisation && project.person.organisation.hourly_rate) ||
    user.preference.hourly_rate
  else
    user.preference.hourly_rate
  end
end
```